# Enforce Windows format in System.IO.Path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cross-platform

We have a **.NET Core 3.1** application deployed in **Linux Docker container**. It retrieves some data from another internal REST API. One of the fields in HTTP response is `FilePath`, which is path in **Windows** format (ex. `K:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\file.txt`).

We would like to remove file name from the path. For this, we wanted to use [Path.GetDirectoryName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getdirectoryname?view=netcore-3.1), but it is OS-dependent. If we run it on development machine running Windows, it correctly removes the file name. If we run it on Linux (inside Docker container), we get an empty string because `\` is a valid character in UNIX file name.

Since we *know* that the path will be in Windows format, is there any way to tell `Path.GetDirectoryName` not to be OS-specific? Does there exist any C# path handling library specifically designed to handle working with *Windows* paths, even on UNIX systems? I know that the paradigm of .NET Core is to be cross-platform, but in our use case we want to enforce Windows rules for path handling even on Linux.

Comment: Since it’s just removing the file name it should be doable easily with “remove everything after last \”. Library suggestions are off topic here, depending what other features you need the functions are quite simple to implement (or copy from .NET source code) and use in your application.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yes, I also thought about implementing the function by myself. I was just wondering if there already exists some library specifically designed for Windows path handling (ex. `WindowsPath.GetDirectoryName(...)`). I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I have made this function, which ensures the path will be optimal for the operating system you are running.

It works as simple as passing the path string and it returns the correct one.

```
/// <summary>
/// Ensures a directory contains correct Separator characters.
/// For better understanding, go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar
/// </summary>
public static string EnsureDirectory(string directory)
{
    string sepChar = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString();
    string altChar = Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar.ToString();

    if (!directory.EndsWith(sepChar) && !directory.EndsWith(altChar))
        directory += sepChar;

    if (OperatingSystem.IsWindows())
        return directory.Replace(altChar, sepChar);

    return directory.Replace("\\", sepChar);
}
```

I won't go so far as to call it the best solution, but it works great for a cross-platform CLI tool I created.